# sample or minimum Tag cloud example in c++

Tags: c++, tag-cloud

I have got project of Tagcloud in c++, from my university. I have googled alot to find some basic version of the Tagcloud. But everything is in the .net/java. Is not possible to make Tagcloud in c++?  I failed to find any minimal c++ example on web.

> 1. Possibility of making TagCloud in c++?
> 2. Any place to find the minimum/basic example of code to do Tag cloud in C++?

Yeah, its bad to ask minimum working example. But I failed to find soemthing.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. This question is better suited for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework but I'll bite...

1. Nail down the C++ graphics renderer you will use. OpenGL is doable but has a difficult learning curve but also gives you the ability to be (somewhat) cross-platform compatible with help from projects like [Angle](https://github.com/google/angle). Just remember that "the devil is in the details" when rendering text in C++ and text rendering alone is a fun task. If you choose to limit your support to say Windows, there are plenty of examples using C++ to draw text. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756692(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. If the TagCloud(Also called a WordCloud) will be interactive, decide on a simple user input abstraction that compliments your rendering choice and do a lot of "Hit" testing to insure you map the inputs from "screen space" to "world space" correctly (also fun across devices).
3. Once these pieces are in place (**only after step 1 and 2**), explore algorithms around the web and research heavily into other publicly available works that will inspire you to get on a whiteboard. At this point the problem comes does to a simple area and 2D collision problem (collisions being "Word" overlap in your case).

Here is the first results I pulled back and already it seems like a promising lead.

[Word Cloud Generation](https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/)

> Attempt to place the word at some starting point: usually near the middle, or somewhere on a central horizontal line.
>   If the word intersects with any previously placed words, move it one step along an increasing spiral. Repeat until no intersections are found.

Comment: Yes, it is kind of assignment for my semester.

Thank you @JosephRosson . Cup in my hand and tears in my eyes says thanks to you. :)  Well its nice , step by step approach. Then my first goal is to generate/render  the simple  text in c++ using min and max size, colour.

Comment: Sure thing. I've edited my answer with a bit more info. Hope it helps and good luck at university